# allowing only a particular email address

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, validation, overriding

I am working on an MVC project and i need to verify the email address for a particular group. For instance only the people with emailID@stanford.edu can register.I did try data annotations but it only verifies the email address, not a substring. How can i check if the email address consists of @stanford.edu ? Thank you in advance.

So, based on the suggestion i tried this one, however i get error during build that:
no suitable method found to override. I tried this.

```
/*
 * Attribute to validate schools
 */
public class ValidateSchoolAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public string stanfordEmail { get; set; }
    public string harvardEmail { get; set; }

    public override bool IsValid(String value)
    {
        if (value == null){
            return true;
        }

        char[] delimiterCharacter = { '@' };
        String text = value;

        String[] words = text.Split(delimiterCharacter);

        if( words.Equals("stanford.edu") ||words.Equals("harvard.edu")  ){
               return true;
        }
        else{
              return false;
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `[RegularExpression]` attribute

```
[RegularExpression(@".*@(harvard|stanford)\.edu")]
[EmailAddress]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

Comment: This was an awesome way to do it. never thought about it.

Answer (score 1):

you should make custom validation attribute.

something like this

`public class OnlyStanfordEmailAttribute: ValidationAttribute`

and then override `IsValid` function.

if you want client side validation too you can follow [this tutorial](http://thewayofcode.wordpress.com/tag/custom-unobtrusive-validation/)

Comment: try googling this `string split C#`, hint: user `string.Split()`